# WP Querying posts by names

Tags: php, wordpress, args

I would like to query some posts(posttype page) by their name. It works perfectly when I query just one post with this args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'name' => "media"
);
```

I think this should work easy with this args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'name' => array( 'media', 'lms-efront'),
);
```

But when I have an array of names it doesn't work and I get all pages, so the argument-array has not any effects(post names are correct).

I have no idea why my code doesn't work as it should, do you know what's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use name parameter as an array in argument instead of you need to used `post_name__in`. If you want to display particular post then you can use post id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` parameter accepts only one post. To retrieve multiple posts using an array use `post_name__in` instead. [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_name__in' => array( 'media', 'lms-efront'),
);
```